# Random URL for update action in a State Machine like Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, state-machine

I'm developing an app that is much similar to a State Machine.

After create a "person", there are attributes left null, that have to be filled yet through "update" actions.

I defined a "unique_token" function in my model, so when creating and updating the person, a new unique string is assigned.

Later, I defined "/:unique_token" in my routes for the "edit" and "update" actions.

Later, In my controller, for "edit" and "udpate", I defined:

@person = Person.find_by_unique_token(params[:unique_token])

BUT!

I get an error because the update action still tries to find an ID.

How should I override that?

There's a better approach for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what you exactly mean by `I get an error because the update action still tries to find an ID.` "Tries to find" — how? ID as in person id?

Comment: yes. the update call still tries to find a controller "person", action "update", and id "params[:id]". but i'm not requiring that attribute so it fails.

Comment: what happens when you tru to find it with 'where'? This wizard tut is another approach: http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wow, easy as:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_unique_token, :only => [:edit]

  def authenticate_unique_token
    person = Person.find_by_unique_token(params[:unique_token])
    if person.blank? || person.id != params[:id].to_i
      raise "whatever"
    end
  end
```

i hope this could help anyone!